# Python -- optional arguments for a function

Tags: python

Say I want to build a function that either adds two numbers `a` and `b` , or subtracts them and adds a third number `c` and subtracts the fourth number `d`. I intend to specify which of the two operations is to be performed by an argument `sum`; if this is `True`, the first operation is performed, if `False`, then the second operations is performed. I would write this as:

```
def f(a, b, c, d, sum=True):
    if sum: return a+b
    else: return a-b+c-d
```

For example, `f(1,2,3,4)` returns `3`, while `f(1,2,3,4,sum=False)` returns `-2`, as expected. Clearly, though, `c` and `d` only need to be defined when `sum=False`. How do I do this? I've tried setting `c` and `d` as *args, but I keep getting errors of the type "unsupported operand" or "positional argument follows keyword argument".

Comment: `c=None, d=None`…?! BTW, the signature appears redundant. Why do you need the `sum` argument when the presence or absence of `c` and `d` already signify the same thing…?

Comment: In adition to @deceze 's comment, I wanted to add that this smells like bad design. When you have a function that behaves differently depending on how many arguments are passed to it, you should ask yourself: why not use two different functions?

Comment: You should notice that `sum` is totally redundant.

Comment: To everyone commenting: the example in the post is not my actual code -- my actual code is a very long method within a class so it wouldn't make sense to post it all here. Clearly "sum" is redundant above, but it is not in my code. Obviously there's no way you would know so I thank you anyways :)

Comment: It's rather obvious this isn't your real code, but we can only critique what we actually see. Ensure you don't have an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a default value of `None` for c and d:

```
def f(a, b, c=None, d=None, sum=True):
    if sum:
        return a+b
    else: 
        return a-b+c-d
```

This also allows you to add error-checking logic to your function - check whether c and d are present when sum is False:

```
def f(a, b, c=None, d=None, sum=True):
    if sum: 
        return a+b
    else: 
        if None in (c, d):
            raise TypeError('f requires c and d args with parameter sum=False')
        return a-b+c-d
```

Comment: I'd omit the error checking, since `+ None` will already raise a TypeError…

Answer (score 3):

Others have given the way you can do it, but at a more fundamental level I'd ask why this is even the same method? Seems to me you have two different methods here, f_sum and f (or whatever), one takes two parameters and the other 4.

<strike>Or if it's a more complex operation and c and d are just additional parameters / attributes, you could default them to whatever the null value is e.g. for addition just default them to 0:</strike>

```py
def f(a, b, c=0, d=0)
```

`a+b-0+0` won't do anything so if these parameters are not provided the result will be identical to a+b without even needing a conditional or magical flag.
sorry missed that the second case was a `-` b and misread it as a +

Comment: @Stefan Some other algorithm than demonstrated here. That's really covered where it shouldn't even be the same method to begin with.

Comment: @StefanPochmann if the example provided is the actual function, the body would become `return a - b + c - d`, nothing else.

Comment: @StefanPochmann ah sorry I mistread the second case as `a + b + c - d`. In that case the first suggestion applies: they should be two separate functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My actual code is a bit more complicated -- I intentionally made the example in my post as simple as possible, but my actual code is not a summation/subtraction function. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: @martin looks to me like it's two functions then, possibly delegating to one another.

Comment: I'd like it to be a single function because it is actually a method within a class that operates slightly differently depending on whether a given condition is true or false. However the method is very long, so having two separate methods would be a pain.

Comment: @martin It sounds like some refactoring is in order then perhaps. This is impossible to help you with in a concrete way though without seeing your actual code, obviously. Consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is:

```py
def f(a, b, c=None, d=None, sum=True):
  if sum: return a + b
  else: return a - b + c - d
```

However, you could further simplify it to this:

```py
def f(a, b, c=0, d=0):
  return a - b + c - d
```

As the values of c and d depend on whether `sum` is true or false.

Answer (score 1):

This solves your problem:

```
def f(a, b, c=0, d=0, sum=True):
    if sum: return a+b
    else: return a-b+c-d
```